# Best way to store and process user editable html templates

Tags: php, database

I am working on building a application where user gets a canvas(not html canvas, a work area) with many features.

**For Eg:**

1. User can add/edit/delete - text/image/shapes
2. User can move(drag)/rotate/resize elements.
3. Save their work.
4. And similar many features.

**NOTE:** Till now I have been storing the user template data in database as plain html. But I have a feeling that it is wrong what I am doing.

I want know what is the best approach to save & process their templates they create.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/): `The Caja Compiler is a tool for making third party HTML, CSS and JavaScript safe to embed in your website.` And they would be no problem for storing html.

Comment: Using jQuery : `$('a#save').click(function() { saveDraft(myDraft); });`

Comment: Why not use CKEditor and save it in a database?

Comment: I am trying to do something like [canva](https://canva.com) tool editor.